# .buckconfig for ReactNative project

Tags: facebook, react-native, buck, nuclide-editor

i am playing around with react native. And i read a lot about `buckbuild` system. Now i am trying to connect those two (*in order to get the full potential in nuclide editor*).

Does anybody have a tip for me how to generate a `buckconfig` file for an existing react native project? Is this even possible automatically? If not, does anybody have a working project with buckbuild and react native?

I would also appreciate all kind of tutorials that are about react native & buckbuild.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved, now since it is part of React Native CLI.

react-native version 0.62:

```
[android]
  target = Google Inc.:Google APIs:23

[maven_repositories]
  central = https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```